# Istio sidecar upstream pod reconnection issue

Tags: kubernetes, grpc, istio, amazon-eks

I'm running istio 1.0.6 (no mTLS) on our EKS cluster and am experiencing connection issues between two pods that I can't seem to figure out.

I have a gRPC client (`abc-client`) and server (`abc-server`) running both written in go. The cluster has automatic sidecar injection enabled, so both have it running.
Everything is working fine if I just start the two services, but whenever the server restarts, the client is not able to reconnect to it. From the restart onwards I continuously get the following error message on the client:

`{"level":"error","error":"rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers","time":"2019-03-19T12:07:52Z","message":"abc-server service unhealthy"}`

Without the istio sidecar the reconnection is working immediately. 
When I look at the sidecar logs of the `abc-client` I see a lot of the following messages for the health checks the client is trying to do:

`2019-03-19T12:09:41.527Z] "POST /grpc.health.v1.Health/CheckHTTP/2" 200 UF 5 0 1002 - "-" "grpc-go/1.15.0" "6a874d67-9c43-4b67-ad24-7337a26cac8d" "abc-server.abc-namespace:8086" "172.31.18.194:8086" outbound|8086||abc-server.abc-namespace.svc.cluster.local - 172.31.18.194:8086 172.31.22.131:44994`

My takeaway from these logs is that the proxy is experiencing problems connecting to the upstream server that is not there anymore, hence the `UF` flag (upstream failure) but is still returning a `200` status code to the client. To me it seems that this behaviour doesn't trigger a reconnection.

I have not any `VirtualService`s or `DestinationRule`s set up, it's just a simple istio cluster with the sidecars enabled.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What are your Kubernetes `Service` & `Deployment` configs?

Comment: What's the output of `istioctl proxy-status`? Did you try to restart the Pilot?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is connecting to headless services. My `service.yaml` looked like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: grpc-test-server
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: grpc-test-server
    role: grpc-test-server
  ports:
    - name: grpc
      port: 9999
      targetPort: grpc
```

As per the issues [#10659](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/10659) and [#7495](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/7495) istio doesn't work yet with headless services.

So, if you don't need your service to be headless, you can just remove `clusterIP: None` from the yaml and everything should work as expected.

I still don't know though how to make statefulsets work which [require](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#limitations) headless services.